# How to make an equation in R for each individual cell

Tags: r, if-statement, cell

I have 2 columns of different size, A and B.

A | B

5 | 4
1 | 2
3 |

How do I say `If CellA is < CellB then give me CellB-CellA?` So it calculates:

"5(A1) is bigger than 4(B1) and 2(B2)" so no results

"1(A2) is smaller than 4(B1) and 2(B2)" so we have 3 and 1

"3(A3) is smaller than 4(B1) and bigger than 2(B2)" so we have 1

**Result = (3, 1, 1)**

The closest I got was:
`if (A < B) {B - A}`

But that only works with columns of same size, I want each individual cell of Column A to interact with each individual cell of column B. How can I do that?

Comment: Are these columns of a data frame, so (B3) is NA, or are these vectors outside a data frame?

Comment: Those are columns of 2 diferent CSV files I'm using `read.csv2` and `File$Column`

Comment: There is no NA in either column

Comment: Downvote for lack of data. Desperately need [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the columns of different sizes then it must be list and not data.frame so the solution :

```r
listAB <- list(A = c(5,1,3) , B = c(4,2))

equ <- function(li){
  result <- vector("numeric")
  for (x in li$A){
    result <- append(result , sapply(li$B , function(y) if(x < y) y - x))
  }
  unlist(result)
}

equ(listAB)
#> [1] 3 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The code works, but only if I put the numbers individualy on the `c()`, when I try to put my data it just says: `> equ(listAB)` `numeric(0)` but it does not give me the numbers. My data reads `is.numeric() TRUE` so I don't know why is not working.

Comment: Would you please share your data to help

Comment: I am using `read.csv2` to read a file, then `File$Column` to select column A, Same thing with Column B. Each column has about 200 lines. Is that what you meant, or there is some way for me to attach my file, so is more clear?

Comment: That is ok , you must make a ‘list’ with arguments A which column A from you data and the same with B then apply ‘equ’ function

Comment: Ok, I did `b <- list(Tayra[,1])` `a <- list(Ocelot[,1])`
`listAB <- list(a , b)` selecting the column I want from the dataframe and turning into a list, but the result of "equ" function still is `numeric(0)` is there any information I can give to help solve the situation? Dataframe Tayra has 150 rows, and Ocelot has 200 rows, can it be the ammount of information is too large to be processed?

Comment: Try `listAB <- list(A = Tayra[,1] ,  B = Ocelot[,1] )` and call `equ(listAB)`